# C++ Passing a Function as a parameter, to execute at a certain point

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I've been looking into how to pass a function as a parameter to another function in C++.

I'm not sure I understand the terminology correctly so I haven't found exactly what I'm looking for online. I thought I could better explain it as a question.

I'm trying to pass a function as an argument which takes place at a certain point in the function it's passed too.

Here's some pseudo-code to better explain my query:

```
    myNewFunction( passedFunction_1, passedFunction_2 ){

            //do some magic in OpenGL
                execute passedFunction_1
            //do some magic in OpenGL
                execute passedFunction_2
            //do some magic in OpenGL
                execute passedFunction_1 (again)
            //do some magic in OpenGL
    }
```

I hope you understand. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you just need help with the syntax of doing this in C++?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. I have my functions already. I'm just trying to implement something in the order of the function above. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we're talking about C++ and not C, you should use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). It's safer, and you can also use it to do more complex things like testing for existence, binding / currying...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

#using namespace std;

typedef function<void (void)> tVoidFunction;
typedef function<void (int)> tVoidFunctionTakingIntParameter;
typedef function<int (float)> tIntFunctionTakingFloatParameter;

void combinedFunction( tVoidFunction fvoid, tVoidFunctionTakingIntParameter fInt, tIntFunctionTakingFloatParameter fIntFromFloat){
  if (fvoid) {
    fvoid();
  }
  if (fInt && fIntFromFloat) {
    static const float magicValue = 42.f;
    int convertedValue = fIntFromFloat(magicValue);
    fInt(convertedValue);
  }
}

void helloWorld() {
  cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
int floatToInt(float f) {
  return floor(abs(f));
}
void doSomethingWithAnInt(int i) {
  cout << "doSomethingWithAnInt: " << i << endl;
}
...

void doWeirdThings() {
  combinedFunction(helloWorld, doSomethingWithAnInt, floatToInt);
}
```

Ho illustrate why this is better than C-style function pointers, here are a couple (somewhat contrived) examples using [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and a lambda to do some more interesting functional stuff:

```
struct Foo {
  void doSomethingWithAnInt(int i) {
    cout << "Foo instance @" << this << " got: " << i << endl;   
  }
}
int doSomethingWithTwoFloats(float f1, float f2) {
   return floor(sqrt(abs(f1 + f2)));
}

...

void doWeirderThingsThanBefore() {
  Foo someFoo;
  auto someFooDoesSomethingWithAnInt = bind(&Foo:doSomethingWithAnInt, &someFoo);
  static const float anotherMagicValue = 69.f;
  auto doSomethingWithTheMagicValue = bind(&doSomethingWithTwoFloats, anotherMagicValue);
  auto helloLambda = [](){
    cout << "Hello, Lambda!" << endl;
  };

  combinedFunction(helloLambda, someFooDoesSomethingWithAnInt, doSomethingWithTheMagicValue);
}
```

Comment: This is also a great example. Are you able to pass an array as one of the function's parameters being passed? eg: `typedef function<int (float, float[])> newFunc`

Comment: You can use any function signature you like.

Answer (score 1):

The latest standard defines a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) class for doing exactly this, and is probably the easiest approach (especially considering the perhaps intimidating syntax of C function pointers).

The syntax would be something like:

```
myNewFunction( std::function<void()> passedFunction_1, std::function<void()> passedFunction_2 ){
        //do some magic in OpenGL
            passedFunction_1();
        //do some magic in OpenGL
            passedFunction_2()
        //do some magic in OpenGL
            passedFunction_1();
        //do some magic in OpenGL
}
```

Instantiating a `std::function` is done by identifying the function that you're wanting to pass around, just as you would if you were using raw C function pointers (one of the nice things about `std::function` is that it plays so nicely with C function pointers). Something like the following:

```
void do_stuff(std::function<void()> another_function)
{
    // Doing stuff

    another_function(); // Invoking the parameter
}

void something_extra()
{
    // Does something else
}

int main()
{
    std::function<void()> the_function = &something_extra;

    // Invoke do_stuff, with something_extra as the function being passed in
    do_stuff(the_function);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. I'm going to give this a go too. Thanks for posting. Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Define `myNewFunction` so that it takes two other functions.
`passFunction1` as well as `passFunction2` are pointers to functions that expect no arguments and return nothing.

```
void myNewFunction(void (*passFunction1)(),
                   void (*passFunction2())
{
    passFunction1();
    passFunction2();
    passFunction1();
}
```

Define a function that takes no arguments, does somethings, and returns nothing.

```
void foo()
{
   // Do something useful
}
```

Define another function that takes no arguments, does somethings, and returns nothing.

```
void bar()
{
   // Do something useful
}
```

Call the first function using the last two functions.

```
myNewFunction(foo, bar);
```

Comment: Regarding the pointers to functions, can they be stored in anything so they can be executed during another function? I'll update my pseudo-code above.

Comment: Yes, they can be stored for future usage.

Comment: Ohh. I'm with you now. I think I understand. Thanks for clarifying that. I'll give it a go now. Thanks for posting.

Comment: I'd suggest using typedefs for all of your functions , to increase code readability.

Comment: And if the functions are going to be resolved at compile-time then you can use a template instead of a function pointer.

Comment: What would happen if `foo` needed it's own parameter? For example a radius value?

Comment: @Reanimation, in that case, the argument to `myNewFunction` needs to be changed to `void (*passFunction1)(double)`. You also have to figure out whether the argument to be used to call `foo` is hard coded in `myNewFunction` or is going to be passed as an additional argument to `myNewFunction`.